# How to add a value to invoice from addons/stock_account/stock.py in Odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

At stock.piking model, I have a personalized value stored in the database: sbf_releve

I need to send this value to account.invoice, when it creates a new invoice

The invoice data is prepared at addons/stock_account/stock.py

```
class stock_picking(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    def _get_invoice_vals(self, cr, uid, key, inv_type, journal_id, origin, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        partner, currency_id, company_id, user_id = key
        if inv_type in ('out_invoice', 'out_refund'):
            account_id = partner.property_account_receivable.id
            payment_term = partner.property_payment_term.id or False
        else:
            account_id = partner.property_account_payable.id
            payment_term = partner.property_supplier_payment_term.id or False
        return {
            'origin': origin,
            'date_invoice': context.get('date_inv', False),
            'user_id': user_id,
            'partner_id': partner.id,
            'account_id': account_id,
            'payment_term': payment_term,
            'type': inv_type,
            'fiscal_position': partner.property_account_position.id,
            'company_id': company_id,
            'currency_id': currency_id,
            'journal_id': journal_id,
        }
```

In my own module, I'm trying to override this method:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class stock_picking(osv.osv):
    _name = "stock.picking"
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    _columns = {
        'sbf_regroupement': fields.boolean('Regroupement', copy=True),
        'sbf_releve': fields.boolean('Relevé', copy=True),
    }

    def create(self, cr, user, vals, context=None):
        context = context or {}
        if ('name' not in vals) or (vals.get('name') in ('/', False)):
            ptype_id = vals.get('picking_type_id', context.get('default_picking_type_id', False))
            sequence_id = self.pool.get('stock.picking.type').browse(cr, user, ptype_id, context=context).sequence_id.id
            vals['name'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get_id(cr, user, sequence_id, 'id', context=context)
        opartner = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, user, vals['partner_id'])
        if ('sbf_releve' not in vals):
            vals['sbf_releve'] = opartner.sbf_releve
        if ('sbf_regroupement' not in vals):
            vals['sbf_regroupement'] = opartner.sbf_regroupement
            # self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, [prod_id], context=ctx)[0]
        return super(stock_picking, self).create(cr, user, vals, context)


    def _get_invoice_vals(self, cr, uid, key, inv_type, journal_id, origin, context=None):



        if context is None:
            context = {}
        partner, currency_id, company_id, user_id = key
        if inv_type in ('out_invoice', 'out_refund'):
            account_id = partner.property_account_receivable.id
            payment_term = partner.property_payment_term.id or False
        else:
            account_id = partner.property_account_payable.id
            payment_term = partner.property_supplier_payment_term.id or False

        sbf_releve = partner.sbf_releve
        vals = super(stock_picking, self)._get_invoice_vals(cr, uid, key, inv_type, journal_id, origin, context)

        vals['sbf_releve'] = True

        return vals
```

But it just doen't work. Why? It works when coping the values from sale.order to stock.picking but not to account.invoice

Answer (score 0):

In order to override a member function, you need to create a subclass:

```
class my_stock_picking(stock_picking):

    def get_invoice_vals(<your parameters>):
          <your function body>
```

For any function not defined in your subclass, it will use the original stock_picking function instead.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want to transfer some of your custom fields from `stock.picking` into `account.invoice`. I have done something similar but for me I passed from `stock.move` to `account.invoice.line`. You should be able to adapt the code below for your case.

```
class stock_move(osv.osv):
_inherit = "stock.move"

def _get_invoice_line_vals(self, cr, uid, move, partner, inv_type, context=None):
    ret = super(stock_move, self)._get_invoice_line_vals(cr, uid, move, partner, inv_type, context=context)

    print "blah blah blah::::",move.date_expected

    if move.date_expected:
        ret['x_delivery_date'] = move.date_expected

    return ret
```

Here date_expected for each product was supposed to transfer to the account.invoice.line as well. I have already made a custom x_delivery_date  in the account.invoice.line. Also update the **__openerp__.py** and include '**account**' in the depends section. I had an issue for this too. Hope it helps.